# How can I return all user custom profile fields in an array?

Tags: templating, user-profile, usermodel

Hi I'm sure this is simple but it is eluding me. I want to pull out all the user profile fields with twig as an array that I can then check. When I dump the user or currentUser data it does not show any of the profile fields I have created in the returned object. I can however still access these fields with user.customfieldname. How can I return the array I am looking for?

Comment: You might want to check out a plugin called inspector, which outputs all methods, attributes, etc, all nicely formatted. `{{ currentUser.getContent()|inspect }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom field data is accessible via `currentUser.getContent()`.

Using `dump`:

```
{{ dump(currentUser.getContent()) }}
```

Or to output as string:

```
{{ currentUser.getContent()|join(', ') }}
```

Comment: Cheers dump brings back the object. But the output as string fails with 'Array to string conversion' error. I've also tried:

[code]{% set profile = currentUser.getContent() %}

{% for key, value in profile %}
  {{ value }}
  {{ key }}
{% endfor %}

Comment: Hmm... 'join' works fine for me on my test DB. Maybe one of the fields is being returned as an array. Possibly a matrix or table field?

Comment: yep that is exactly what was happening. I added a check to see if any returned data was also an array and it now works fine. Thanks